# NewRelic transactions in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

Magento Commerce 2 comes with NewRelic module-new-relic-reporting module. It automatically logs transactions. It is possible to add custom parameters by calling the newrelic_add_custom_parameter function. Currently NewRelic displays **only** those transactions which are "*Most time consuming*" or with "*Slowest Average Response Time*" or "*Apdex most dissatisfying*" or with "*Highest throughput*". I want the NewRelic dashboard to display **all transactions** if they have a specific custom parameter. How to achieve that?

Comment: You are going to have to customise. Which means you need to think how would you set the parameter. Once you've figured that part you could then look at code and use plugins or rewrites

Comment: I already know (and have already implemented it) how to pass the parameter. And it is visible in NewRelic. But it is only visible if I make the request long enough for the NewRelic to consider that monitorable. If I need to customise stuff in NewRelic, please let me know where exactly to do so, because I can't find the settings